# Prevent Auto Logoff Windows 10

Tags: group-policy

I'm trying to find GPO or registry settings for disabling auto sign out when idle.

It's okay if the display turns off but it shouldn't ask the user to enter a password.
I don't mind the security concerns about this as it's for a very specific scenario.

I've tried applying the following GPO settings with no luck:

- Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit: **0 seconds**
- Allow standby states (S1-S3) when sleeping (plugged in): **Disabled**
- Turn Off the Display (seconds): **1800**
- Creating a Power Plan Option with: **Require a password on wakeup: No**

After the 1800 seconds (30 minutes) the display turns dark as it should but it requires me to log in again.
Anyone knows what can be done?

Comment: Hi, what is your goal ? as the goal of the lock screen is if the computer is unattended no one will use the computer. If it's a computer for a public library, or some open place like that for everyone use, please make sure you have no screensaver gpo too on the user level